# How to change intellij's gradle elephant icon to the classic one

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

The elephant icon of the gradle build-tool doesn't look professional to  non-programmer high ranked entities (in my opinion) , the older icon looks much more professional .

My goal is to find a way to revert back to the previous gradle icon on my IDE.

tried to find this answer on the intellij's documentation without no success,
tried numerous google searches,
investigated plenty of intellij-idea options,
searched stackoverflow's related topics, With no luck.

I'm sure that eventhough this problem isn't code related,
It relates to every java/scala/kotlin programmer who would love to find a solution for this.

Comment: Good luck with that, but frankly, there are better ways to spend your time.

Comment: I find the time for aesthetic issues as well

Comment: While you're there can you change the logo on www.google.com? My 5 year old child could do better, very unprofessional

Comment: At least it doesnt show 50 small elephants all over the screen, when youre presenting a micro-service architecture to your investor.

Comment: I wish stackoverflow can 'haha' to questions like facebook

Comment: Do you have c-levels hovering over your shoulder all day?

Comment: While I couldn't care less about profesionality, the old icon is much more colorful and easier to find when looking at a list of files than the new one, which is the same color as the "gray text file" blending in very well. I prefered the older icon because it was easier to see and to find visually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can clone the Intellij Community edition repo, replace the svg icon. You can then run it from source or compile it into an executable. The location of the icon can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/gradle/resources/icons/gradle.svg). Build instructions are in the readme.